# Python - not printing win message

Tags: python, python-3.x

my code is meant to display a win message when the game is won, but even when its completed the game will display a try again message.

My code looks like

```
import time

print("If A is represented by the symbol #, M by * and N by %, then the word\nMANNA would be represented by the symbols *#%%#")

#Loads files

in_file = open("words.txt", 'rt')
words_loaded = in_file.read()
print(words_loaded)
in_file.close()

print("Here are your clues!")
time.sleep(0.5)

in_file = open("clues.txt", 'rt')
clues_loaded = in_file.read()
print(clues_loaded)
in_file.close()

in_file = open("solved.txt", 'rt')
solved = in_file.read()
in_file.close()

#Menu

def menu():

        play_game = print("1. Play the game")
        instruc = print("2. Instructions")
        question = input("Enter choice")

        if question == "2":
                print("You will given a list of coded words, you have to replace the symbols to letters to get the word")
                print("\n")
                menu()
        else:
                play()

#How many turns user would like

def play():

        global words_loaded

        x = int(input("How many guesses would you like?\n(You'll need atleast 23, only input numbers) \n"))
        for i in range(x):



#symbol replacing

                sym = input("Which symbol do you want to replace? ")
                cha = input("Which character do you want to replace with it? ")

#shows the symbol changes

                words_loaded = words_loaded.replace(sym, cha)
                print("Your Puzzle now looks like... \n")
                print(words_loaded)

#Messages for user if they win or lose

                if words_loaded == solved:
                    print("PUZZLE SOLVED")
        if i ==(x-1):
                print("Better luck next time")
                ask = input("would you like to play again?")

                if ask == "yes":
                        play()
                else:
                        print("bye")
                     Asks if user would like to play again
                Tryagain = input("would you like to play?")

                if Tryagain == "no":
                       print("Thanks for playing")
                else:
                       menu()

menu()
```

it probably needs fixing near the bottom, just thought id include the whole code.

the contents of

words.txt is

```
#+/084&"
#3*#%#+
8%203:
,1$&
!-*%
.#7&33&
#*#71%
&-&641'2
#))85
9&330*
```

solved.txt is

```
acquired
almanac
insult
joke
hymn
gazelle
amazon
eyebrows
affix
vellum
```

clues.txt is

```
A = #
M = *
N = %
```

Comment: check your indentation/location of conditions. You might want to check for i == (x-1) within the loop, and have an else if checking if the puzzle is solved (or the other way around...) Anyways, it looks like, even if you solve the puzzle, it keeps looping... and eventually its failed. You need to break once you have solved the puzzle.

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms Im new to this :/ could you edit the code for me and post it? that would be much appreciated

Comment: Sadly, I don't have a python interpreter installed, and any code I write would be unchecked and likely have some small errors throughout. If no one has posted an answer by the time I am done work, I will go home and install python IDE and make this work for you. (If I do this, I will want your input files, so you might want to paste some sample input files in your opening post.

Comment: @TheOneWhoPrograms Thank you, ive added in the contents of the files into the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an indentation error near `for` loop. Fixing that fixed the problem but I don't get why you asked twice playing again so i changed that to one `if-elif-else` statement.
Also I changed your file opening to `with`s because it's more easy to read and you don't need to `close` them manually.

```
import time

def menu():

        play_game = print("1. Play the game")
        instruc = print("2. Instructions")
        question = input("Enter choice")

        if question == "2":
                print("You will given a list of coded words, you have to replace the symbols to letters to get the word")
                print("\n")
                menu()
        else:
                play()

#How many turns user would like

def play():

        global words_loaded

        x = int(input("How many guesses would you like?\n(You'll need atleast 23, only input numbers) \n"))
        for i in range(x):



#symbol replacing

                sym = input("Which symbol do you want to replace? ")
                cha = input("Which character do you want to replace with it? ")

#shows the symbol changes

                words_loaded = words_loaded.replace(sym, cha)
                print("Your Puzzle now looks like... \n")
                print(words_loaded)

#Messages for user if they win or lose

                if words_loaded == solved:
                    print("PUZZLE SOLVED")
                    break


        if i ==(x-1):
               print("Better luck next time")
#        ask = input("would you like to play again?")

#Asks if user would like to play again
        Tryagain = input("would you like to play?")

        if Tryagain == "yes":
                play()

        elif Tryagain == "no":
               print("Thanks for playing")

        else:
               menu()

print("If A is represented by the symbol #, M by * and N by %, then the word\nMANNA would be represented by the symbols *#%%#")

#Loads files

with open("words.txt", 'rt') as in_file:
        words_loaded = in_file.read()
        print(words_loaded)

print("Here are your clues!")
time.sleep(0.5)

with open("clues.txt", 'rt') as in_file:
            clues_loaded = in_file.read()
            print(clues_loaded)

with open("solved.txt", 'rt') as in_file:
            solved = in_file.read()


#Menu

menu()
```

Comment: thanks so much!! I'll test this in school, you just got me an A* :D

Comment: i just tested it and it worked perfectly, just had to import the time, just gonna edit it so when the user wins, it wont ask to play again, i apprecite your help so much